# Shell Script get CTRL+Z with Trap

Tags: linux, bash, shell, signals, bash-trap

I am trying to get the SIGSTOP <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> signal in my script's `trap`.

When my script is executing, if I **temporarily suspend** from execution, send a SIGSTOP signal<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, it needs to remove the files I create in it and to kill the execution.

I don't understand why the following script doesn't work. But, more important, what is the correct way to do it?

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="temp_folder"
trap "rm -r $DIR; kill -SIGINT $$" SIGSTP

if [ -d $DIR ]
then
    rm -r $DIR
else
    mkdir $DIR
fi
sleep 5
```

**EDIT**:

`SIGSTOP` cannot be trapped, however `SIGTSTP` can be trapped, and from what I understood after [searching on the internet](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2000/06/msg01586.html) and the answer below it's the correct to trap when sending signal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. However, when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> while running the script **it will get stuck**, meaning that the script will be endlessly execute no matter what signals I send afterwards.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is you are trying to suspend a process that is already sleeping.

It is also good practice to use `DIR=$(mktemp -d)` in shell scripts to create temp directories.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is signal (`2`) / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> (`20`):

```
catch_exits() {
        printf "\n$(basename $0): exiting\n" 1>&2
        rm -rf $DIR
        exit 1
}

trap catch_exits 1 2 3 15 20

DIR="$(mktemp -d)"
read -p "not sleeping" test
```

if you send a function to the background (such as for a cursor spinner) - then you need to disable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> while the long process is running with:

```
trap "" SIGTSTP
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two signals you can't `trap`*, `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`. Use another signal.

<sup>*: without modifying the kernel</sup>

[IEEE standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/trap.html):

> Setting a trap for SIGKILL or SIGSTOP produces undefined results.

Comment: Ok, that's understandable. But why wont't it work with `SIGTSTP`? And get the output in the edit?