# Closing the files with bash

Tags: bash

I have a running bash script, that runs a program 'n' times in a loop. That program opens a txt for example, counts, then write another txt. At the start of the script, it deletes all of the output txts. But if I kill the running script with Ctrl-Z, and I want to delete all of the txt-s, or the program itself, I can't delete the txts that the program actually counted with, it writes the text is 'busy'. I could understand why it works like that, but in another ubuntu, i could delete all of them.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Can you trap the signal and then delete the files? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182454/shell-script-get-ctrlz-with-trap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl-Z doesn't kill the script, it *suspends* it.
The process remains alive, it can be resumed,
and therefore it doesn't release the resources it is using.

If you want to kill the script, type Ctrl-C instead.
When the script is really killed,
there will be nothing to keep the file open and you will be able to delete.

Comment: Super, thank you! When i read, how to kill a script, maybe it was Ctrl-C, but i could change it perhaps, by time...

Comment: Control-Z doesn't put the script in the background; it simply stops it from running. You would have to additionally use the `bg` command to continue running the script in the background.